# Docker hub image cache doesn't seem to be working

Tags: docker, docker-registry, dockerhub

We have a continuous integration pipeline on circleci that does the following:

1. Loads repo/image:mytag1 from the cache directory to be able to use cached layers
2. Builds a new version: docker build -t repoimage:mytag2
3. Saves the new version to the cache directory with docker save
4. Runs tests
5. Pushes to docker hub: docker push repo/image:mytag2

The problem is with step 5. The push step takes 5 minutes every time. If I understand it correctly, docker hub is meant to cache layers so we don't have to re-push things like the base image and dependencies if they are not updated.

I ran the build twice in a row, and I see a lot of crossover in the hash of the layers being pushed. Yet rather than "Image already exists" I see "Image successfully pushed".

[Here's](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jtmarmon/4a376cbb5e70d1ce2a7e/raw/79c7b8cb49c5981aed92b7a5e20855c56ecc385f/dockerhub_slow_build1.txt) the output of build 1's docker push, and [here's build 2](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jtmarmon/b13ee9c7496ad6b31e21/raw/262662daf19224c1da491b337b84739a0056da56/dockerhub_slow_build2.txt)

If you diff those two files you'll see that only 2 layers differ in each build:

```
< ca44fed88be6: Buffering to Disk
< ca44fed88be6: Image successfully pushed
< 5dbd19bfac8a: Buffering to Disk
< 5dbd19bfac8a: Image successfully pushed
---
> 9136b10cfb72: Buffering to Disk
> 9136b10cfb72: Image successfully pushed
> 0388311b6857: Buffering to Disk
> 0388311b6857: Image successfully pushed
```

So why is it that all the images have to re-push every time?

Comment: What version of docker is running in CircleCI? I wonder if this is a bug; what happens if you push the *same image/tag* multiple times? Basically, docker *should* check for existence of a layer, permits it's in the same repository. Also, are you pushing to docker hub?

Comment: For example; https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/18866

Comment: yep pushing to the same repo in docker hub. I've filed an issue here (https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/19583) running some more tests based on your suggestions and i'll post the extra info there

Comment: Cool, thanks for that!

Comment: Hah, looked at the GitHub issue, and actually was thinking about the save/load step being the cause. Decided to ask for repeated push first. Anyway, good to see you found the cause.

Comment: unfortunately no solution yet :( hoping the circleci team can come up with something clever

Answer (score 1):

Using a different tag creates a different image which, when pushed,  cannot rely on the cache.

For example the two commands:

```
$ docker commit -m "thing" -a "me" db65bf421f96 me/thing:v1
$ docker commit -m "thing" -a "me" db65bf421f96 me/thing:v2
```

yield utterly distinctimages even though they were created from identical images (db65bf421f96). When pushed, dockerhub must treat them as completely separate images as can be seen with:

```
$ docker images
REPOSITORY     TAG      IMAGE ID
me/thing       v2       f14aa8ac6bae
me/thing       v1       c7d72ccc1d71
```

The image IDs are unique and thus the images are unique even only if they vary in tags.

You could say "docker should recognize them as being bit for bit identical" and thus treat them as cachable. But it doesn't (yet).

The only surprise for me in your example is that you got any duplicate image IDs at all.

Authoritative (if less explanatory) [documentation can be found at docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/dockerimages/#updating-and-committing-an-image) in "Build your own images".

Comment: welp that's annoying. thanks for the info! surely people aren't all waiting for 10 minute builds just because they use docker...is the only workaround to just keep pushing the same tag (overwriting the old one)? seems like a gross approach to me

Comment: @jtmarmon I'm as new to docker as everyone is. I don't think it unreasonable behavior that in a CI setting that successive builds should be tagged the same. It may make sense for you to have an internal build number that is not part of the tag. This is not so different than the docker meta-tag :latest; if I get image:latest, that's precisely what I want even if it is different than yesterday's image:latest.

Comment: how does one rollback to an older version of the code without having a new tag per deploy

Comment: Rolling back to an older version seems to me to be outside docker's model of operation and more in the VCS/CI camp.

Comment: Or just don't make a novel tag for every single build. Tags should be meaningful in a way that build numbers aren't. I'm running Chrome 48.0.2564.82 this minute, but is that `.82` suitable for a docker tag? I wouldn't use it that way.

Answer (score 0):

The process should work as you described. In fact we're building all of our images in this way without problems. Usually there are just a few changes to the topmost layers and only those are pushed to the registry - otherwise the whole concept of image layers would be useless.

See [here](https://git.hrzg.de/phundament/app/builds/17395) for an example. Only the two topmost layers have changed, are pushed for `:latest` and for `:4.0.2` there's no push at all. We're tagging images with git tags and for some projects we even tag images with `git describe` - to get the rollback functionality, just in case.

You can get the project source-code also from [GitHub](https://github.com/phundament/app) to try it out.

A few things to note about the setup: We're using a self-hosted GitLab CI with a customized [runner](https://github.com/schmunk42/docker-gitlab-runner) which runs `docker` and `docker-compose` on an isolated host with Docker 1.9.1, but that should not make any difference.

There may be also differences in the registry version, I had the feeling (but I am not 100% sure) that some older repos on DockerHub are still running on registry `v1`, newer ones always on `v2` - so you may try creating a new repo and see if the issue still occurs.

Please note that the behavior for tags described above does only apply when pushing the same image-name, if you push the same image layers with another name, you always need to push all layers, despite the fact that all layers should already exists on the registry, so I guess `repo/image:mytag1` and `repoimage:mytag2` actually go to `repo/image` and the missing slash is just a typo.

Another cause could be that your images are built on different hosts on Circle CI, but then you should also get different layer IDs, so I think this is not very likely.

I suggest to build an image manually and try to reproduce the problem or contact Circle CI about this issue.